I found 3 dead hummingbirds in pool area the last couple of weeks. Baffled why
In the last couple of weeks, we have found 3 dead hummingbirds.  I have 2 feeders in deck area and always have at least 5 to 6 birds everyday. (We live in middle Georgia.) I change the nectar everyday.  I clean the feeders regularly.  This is the first year we have found deceased birds.  It breaks my heart.  I am baffled and why I am reaching out.

You could find local bird rescue folks and ask about the prevalence of bird flu in the area.

Perhaps check the quality of the feed you are putting out. You've been doing this for a while, have you changed the feed this year? if not, has the same supplier changed their feed?

Why do you change the nectar every day?

@Mike - where I live daily change is pretty much required for it to not start fermenting or otherwise going off...

Two main things come to mind. If its been raining, the rain could be literally forcing them into the water.  Beyond that they could be attempting to bathe or otherwise attracted to the water without realizing how deep it is.
Drowning isn't rare for hummingbirds in deep water, I don't think there is a way to keep them from landing in it without actually covering the pool, if you add some floating things to the water they could climb on to get out, or a safer place for them to bathe-- or both-- that might help.
